# command-line app to create simple one-line menus with arrow-keys navigation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, menu, console

I'm curious what's the easy way of building command-line menu like on the picture? There are some more cool options like using `dialog` app and other apps like that, but i just want to have very simple *in-line* solution and not pollute the whole screen.

NB: on example gif you see replacement of string in the command line above the menu, but i do not need that.
**I just need cool simple menu(s) in my bash script(s).**

Thanks!

[image: how it may work]

Comment: There is the [`select`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) built-in, but no arrow key navigation there.

Comment: yep, but no arrow key navigation there :)